# When there is a Parent Component and a Child Component, why is the Child Constructor called before the Parent OnInit?

Tags: angular

My code has two components -

1. Parent
2. Child

Relevant code and output below -

> **parent.component.html**
>
> ```
> <p>parent works!!</p>
> <app-child> </app-child>
> ```
>
> **parent.component.ts**
>
> ```
> export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
>   constructor() {
>     console.log('Logged by Parent constructor');
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>     console.log('Logged by Parent OnInit');
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **child.component.ts**
>
> ```
> export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
>   constructor() {
>     console.log('Logged by Child Constructor');
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>     console.log('Logged by Child OnInit');
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **output in console**
>
> ```
> Logged by Parent constructor
> Logged by Child Constructor
> Logged by Parent OnInit
> Logged by Child OnInit
> ```

I am unable to understand why Parent OnInit is not called immediately after Parent Constructor.

Can I please get an explanation on execution flow that is happening under the hood?

Comment: Constructors are called before lifecycle methods. At first, class is instantiated and then the method of a class is called, which is `OnInit` if component doesn't have `@Input`. If it does have then it's `OnChanges`.

Comment: @Chaka15 Can you please make your comment the answer. I'd like to mark it as one. Thank you!

Comment: Of course, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors are called before lifecycle methods. At first, class is instantiated and then the method of a class is called, which is `OnInit` if component doesn't have `@Input`.

If it does have then it's `OnChanges` that is fired first.